# sort data in descending order in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Descending_Click()
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
j = Worksheets.Count
For k = 1 To j
    Selection.Sort key1:=Range("L2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Next k
End Sub
```

I got above code on the web and made changes as per my requirement. Its working fine but it works on current sheet only, I want to it to work on multiple sheets. Also after running, all data get selected. After running data should not be select. Need expert help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually loop through each worksheet and act on that sheet. As your code is written, there is no specification to loop through the sheets or to work on any specific sheet. The `Selection` statement just works on what is active selected at that moment.

```
Sub Descending_Click()
Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws in Worksheets
    ws.UsedRange.Sort key1:=Range("L2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Next ws
End Sub

'Note: you made need to specify the exact range on the worksheet, depending on how your data is set up. In that case, replace UsedRange with Range("A1:K100") or whatever your range actually is.
```

Comment: Thanks Scott............fine...........small changes made......... next ws in place next k

Comment: good catch @KISHORBHOIR! I edited my post. Please mark as the answer if it indeed solved your issue.